# Alert Dialog causing 'Render Box was laid out' in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout

```
The relevant error-causing widget was
AlertDialog
lib\pages\DoctorPage.dart:157
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#a3b64 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
package:flutter/…/rendering/box.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 1979 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
AlertDialog
lib\pages\DoctorPage.dart:157
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPhysicalShape#5185b relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
package:flutter/…/rendering/box.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 1979 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
AlertDialog
lib\pages\DoctorPage.dart:157
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 348 pos 12: 'child!.hasSize': is not true.
package:flutter/…/rendering/shifted_box.dart:348
The relevant error-causing widget was
AlertDialog
lib\pages\DoctorPage.dart:157
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPhysicalShape#5185b relayoutBoundary=up2
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
package:flutter/…/rendering/box.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 1979 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
AlertDialog
```

This long error is been shown where I am putting my Alert box in the flutter

This is my alert box code

```
class DoctorButtonBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const DoctorButtonBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ButtonBar(
      alignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) {
                  return AlertDialog(
                    scrollable: true,
                    title: "title".text.make(),
                  );
                });
          },
          icon: Icon(
            Iconsax.award5,
            color: AutiTheme.white,
            semanticLabel: "Autisure Assured",
          ),
        ),
        IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Icon(
              CupertinoIcons.arrow_right_circle_fill,
              color: AutiTheme.white,
            ))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Note: I am using this with a listview I Dunno if that is causing the issue but it's not mentioned in error about the list view

My code with the DoctorButtonBar

```
 return VxBox(
            child: Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        DoctorListImage(image: item.imageUrl),
        Expanded(
            child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            "Dr. ${item.name}".text.lg.color(AutiTheme.white).bold.make(),
            item.specialist.text.color(AutiTheme.creamColor).make(),
            10.heightBox,
            const DoctorButtonBar()
          ],
        ))
      ],
    ))
        .color(AutiTheme.primary)
        .shadow2xl
        .rounded
        .square(150)
        .make()
        .onTap(() {})
        .py16();
```

About the page, I am getting some data from a JSON file mapping it, and showing it in a listview.builder(). In that, I have created a batch as a verified batch which Is an icon button so when a user clicks I want to show a alert box by giving some context to the award button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using dialog instead of AlertDialog

```
    showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context){
                  return Dialog(
                    backgroundColor: Color(0xFFfafafa),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                    elevation: 20,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 120, //use height 
                      child: child,
                  );
                });
```

Comment: Thanks working for me but can you tell me what was the problem with the alert dialo

Comment: Unspecified height caused the error

Answer (score 0):

Just to compound answer by Sharyu.

If you would go to [official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html) you will see:

> Because the dialog attempts to size itself to the contents, the content must support reporting its intrinsic dimensions. In particular, this means that lazily-rendered widgets such as ListView, GridView, and CustomScrollView, will not work in an AlertDialog unless they are wrapped in a widget that forces a particular size (e.g. a SizedBox).
> **For finer-grained control over the sizing of a dialog, consider using Dialog directly.**

So basically AlertDialog does not support ListView or GridView unless they are wrapped into widgets that would specify their size.